# Sampling from Nearest Neighbor Density Estimator

Tags: kernel-smoothing, k-nearest-neighbour

The KDE (with variable bandwidth) is defined as $$\hat f(x) = n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nh_x^{-1}K\big(h_x^{-1}(x - X_i)\big).$$
Once the density is estimated, one could sample points as follows: pick a poin from the observed sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ and then sample from the known density $K$ (c.f [simple sampling method for a Kernel Density Estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43674/simple-sampling-method-for-a-kernel-density-estimator))

In the special case where $K$ is assumed to be the uniform density and $h_x$ is chosen as the distance to $x$'s $k$th nearest neighbor, i.e. $h_x = |x - r_k|$, where $r_k$ is the $k$th sample point, ordered by distance to $x$.

Can I proceed in the same way as before, that is, pick a random point from the sample and sample from a uniform distribution?

Comment: It's unclear that your initial description is a valid sampling method.  After all, the algorithm you describe is ambiguous: once you have selected a point from the sample, *what bandwidth do you use to sample from $K$?* In fact, it looks like that in general $\hat f$ is not even a valid density: it won't integrate to unity.

Comment: but assuming the domain of my target density is constant, I could easily scale the density such that it integrates to unity; so I believe that this is no (serious) issue. I am more concerned with the point you mention: what bandwdith should be chosen? I thought about picking a random point $X$ from the sample and then compute the bandwdith as the distance from $X$ to the $k$th nearest neighbors in the sample

Comment: There definitely *is* a serious issue, as revealed by examples in which $\hat f$ is identically zero.

Comment: how would such an example look like? As far as I understood the problem, the KNN density estimator is just proportional to a density